# How to search an object that contains a given string in its key without using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

How would I go about searching an object for a key containing a given string without using a loop?

Here is an example of my object

```
let item = {
  ItemID: 1,
  ItemName: "Box",
  ItemMinHeight: 10,
  ItemMaxHeight: 30,
  ItemMinDepth: 11,
  ItemMaxDepth: 18,
  ItemMinWidth: 20,
  ItemMaxWidth: 50  
};
```

I need to get the key value pairs that would contain "Depth", so it should return 
ItemMinDepth and ItemMaxDepth

Comment: So, you want to search through a list of arbitrary key names and find just the ones that match a partial string, but you don't want to loop through the key names? I don't understand how you think that's going to be possible. It's a bit like someone giving you a stack of index cards with names on them, then saying "find everyone named Bob without looking through the cards"... Why can't you use a loop?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, because I think using es6 would be cleaner. Maybe I should have asked how to do this with es6?

Comment: You can do this with iteration functions, but you'd still be using a "loop". When you have some constraint on how to solve a problem, **explain it**; don't leave everybody with a mystery.

Comment: @Pointy, when i say "loop" i mean for, forEach etc...I thought that with adding ecmascript-6 in the tag would have taken the mystery out of it

Comment: Those functions all are loops. You're not asking how to do it without a loop, you're just asking how to do it without an explicit for loop? I'll answer that new question below.

Comment: Well as the first comment notes, the set of property names is not indexed in any way so the only approach to solve your problem is  linear search of some sort. That could be with `for`, `forEach`, `reduce`, etc. It's purely a matter of opinion and style which way is "better" because they'd all do basically the same thing.

Comment: Why do you want to do this using an iteration method that doesn't look like a loop to you? Is there some objective or is this just an arbitrary constraint?

Comment: @benvc, because I don't know how to get the length of the object so I could do a for loop and using something else seemed like less code

Comment: You don't need the length to loop over an object. Check out [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
const listOfDepthKeys = Object.keys(item).filter(key => key.includes('Depth'));
```

Note this is still using a loop, as `filter` is a loop internally; it's no different from a `for` loop except that you aren't the one writing `for` :)

If you want the values, too:

```
const list = Object.entries(item).filter(entry => entry[0].includes('Depth'));
const pairs = Object.fromEntries(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `lodash/fp` (a full functional variant of Lodash), you can achieve this by this way:

```js
_.flow([
  _.toPairs,
  _.filter(([key, value]) => key.includes('Depth')),
  _.fromPairs
  ])(item)
```

Lodash fp is fully built upon `_.curry` function which allows to build intermediate functions as long as you didn't provide all required parameters. `_.flow` allows to chain functions in an elegant and perfectly combines with curried functions.

Here is the doc of this library https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc

Comment: Without any additional library, `Object.entries().reduce()` could do the same thing.

Comment: Everything possible thanks to a JS library is possible with VanillaJS, I'm just providing an elegant (and easily scalable) way

Comment: Is it more elegant, though? It converts to key/value pairs, filters, then converts back to an object. That's literally the exact same process, in the same number of lines, as the vanilla way.

Comment: I didn't say it was the best way, I'm just demonstrating a library which could really help the OP if he gets harder issues. When you demonstrate something, you start with a simple example, that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash

```
let items = {
  ItemID: 1,
  ItemName: "Box",
  ItemMinHeight: 10,
  ItemMaxHeight: 30,
  ItemMinDepth: 11,
  ItemMaxDepth: 18,
  ItemMinWidth: 20,
  ItemMaxWidth: 50  
};
```

Use lodash keys method

```
const depthItems = {}
_.keys(items).map(key => {
  if(key.indexOf("Depth") !== -1) {
    depthItems[key] = items[key]
  }
})
console.log(depthItems)
```